# filter in ng-repeat by values?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angular-ngmodel

I would like to filter an ng-repeat by a key that has 4 values(1-4) using uib-tabs. Is there a way to do this inline with ng-model on the tab elements? If so, what is the format? For instance, I have an ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in reportsData">{{item.name}} - {{item.packageID}}</div>
```

and in my reportsData array I have

..."packageID": 1,...

Where packageID can be of a value between 1 and 4. The trick is that I want to setup something along the lines of

```
item.packageID >=1
```

How do I do this? Here is an example:

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
 <uib-tab index="0" select="" ng-model="?">
    <uib-tab-heading><span class="pkg-sm-ss pull-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Package 1</uib-tab-heading>
 </uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="1" select="" ng-model="?">
    <uib-tab-heading><span class="pkg-sm-s pull-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Package 2</uib-tab-heading>
 </uib-tab>
 <uib-tab index="2" select="" ng-model="?">
    <uib-tab-heading><span class="pkg-sm-b pull-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Package 3</uib-tab-heading>
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab index="3" select="" ng-model="?">
    <uib-tab-heading><span class="pkg-sm-i pull-left"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Package 4</uib-tab-heading>    
</uib-tab>
```

View Sample  
          
        {{item.name}}

{{item.description | limitTo: 160}}

View Details
         = 4"> = 3"> = 2"> = 1">

I cant get the code to format correctly here but this is what Im trying to do.

Comment: I didn't understand absolutely nothing. Can you explain posting the **code**? Or better provide a plnkr -> http://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: ng-click="show items in array that have a packageID value that is equal to greater than 1" where the value can be 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: Do you have the structure of this array? Show us.

Comment: The array is too large. It has a key and value of packageID where the value is 1,2,3 or 4.

Comment: I treid to simplify my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38386318/change-scope-value-on-ng-click     I will delete this post if that one is answered.