# Change scope value on ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I would like to use tabs to hide and show items in an ng-repeat. Is it possible to change the value of a scope like so?

```
 <a ng-click="packageType = '1'">Package 1</a><a ng-click="packageType ='2'">Package 2</a><a ng-click="packageType = '3'">Package 3</a>
<div ng-repeat="item in packages" ng-show="packageType >=item.packageID">
{{item.name}}</div>
```

and the scope:

```
$scope.packages = [...{ "name": "some name",
                    "packageID": 1}...]
```

Where packageID can be 1, 2 or 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code that does exactly what your asking

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AizRPDQbF26CNUM7QKW9?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div ng-controller="TabCtrl">
      <tabset>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.name}}" active="tab.active" select="onTabSelected(tab.slug)">
          {{ tab.packageId }}
        </tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $routeProvider.when('/', {
              controller: 'MainCtrl'
          }).when('/room/:id', {
              controller: 'RoomCtrl',
          }).when('/dashboard', {
              controller: 'DashboardCtrl'            
          }).otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
          });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
      }]);    

      var TabCtrl = function($scope) {
        $scope.tabs = [{
          slug: 'dashboard',
          name: "Package 1",
          packageId: "some package #1"
        }, {
          slug: 'room-1',
          name: "Package 2",
          packageId: "some package #2"
        }, {
          slug: 'room-2',
          name: "Package 3",
          packageId: "some package #3"
        }];
      };

      RoomCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

      };

      DashboardCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

      };    

      MainCtrl = function($scope, $location) {

        $scope.onTabSelected = function(tab) {
          var route;
          if (typeof tab === 'string') {
            switch (tab) {
              case 'dashboard':
                route = tab;
                break;
              default:
                route = 'rooms/' + tab;
                break;
            }
          }
          $location.path('/' + route);
        };

      };
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that encapsulates what you want to happen on click. That would make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

So I assume packages is an array and what you posted is not your complete code. 
You will want to change your ng-show to say

```
ng-show="packageType == item.packageID"
```

this will only show the div if the packageID is the same as the package type. Your ng-click should work fine. You will want to set a default value for packageType somewhere in your controller however so something shows initially

Comment: thanks but these are tiered packages. If packageID = 1, then I need it to show for 1,2 3 and 4, hence the >=.

Answer (score 0):

You code has a few problems:

You first ng-click is does not have a closing quote.

```
<a ng-click="packageType = '1'>Package 1</a>
```

You set packageType to a string when it is a number later:

```
packageType ='2'
$scope.packages = { "name": "some name",
                    "packageID": 1}
```

You don't need {{}} in the ng-show

```
ng-show="packageType >={{item.packageID}}"
```

I think you meant for packages to be an array instead of an object:

```
$scope.packages = { "name": "some name",
                    "packageID": 1}
```

Example of how to do it is below. I set it to show on the second and third links :

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.packageType = 1;
    $scope.packages = [{
      "name": "some name1",
      "packageID": 2
    }, {
      "name": "some name2",
      "packageID": 2
    }, {
      "name": "some name3",
      "packageID": 2
    }, {
      "name": "some name4",
      "packageID": 3
    }, {
      "name": "some name5",
      "packageID": 3
    }, {
      "name": "some nam6",
      "packageID": 3
    }];
  }
  ExampleController.$inject = ['$scope'];
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='exampleApp'>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <a ng-click="packageType = 1">Package 1</a>
  <a ng-click="packageType = 2">Package 2</a>
  <a ng-click="packageType = 3">Package 3</a>
  <p ng-repeat="item in packages" ng-show="packageType >= item.packageID">{{item.name}}
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this isn't my code, just a quickly typed drummed down version. Thanks for this though! I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Let me clarify: The array I showed is just one of about 50 items. Also, the array is predefined and I can't change the name without rewriting a lot of code, and I'm not understanding the value of prepending the array scope with vm. I removed the curly brackets from the ng-show. Is there an alternative way to do this without modifying the controlelr?

Comment: Also, this only works for exact values. I need to show package 1 if packageID is 1, 2, 3 or 4. package 2 needs to be shown if packageID is 2, 3 or 4, etc.

Comment: @ChristianHill you are starting to describe a filter which is different than what you explained in question. `ng-repeat` supports filters

Comment: I dont think so. My code illustrates what I am trying to achieve. That's why I used >=. This means greater than OR equal to. Obviously it isn't which is why im reaching out to the SO community.

Comment: @ChristianHill but you are adding significant extra watchers that can be avoided with filter

Comment: Please elucidate :) that's really what I was hoping to achieve. The code above was just to illustrate what I am trying to do. I'm open to any suggestion. Essentially, I want to have tabs at the top of the page and by clicking on the tabs, it only shows the items that are included in each package. The problem is that everything included in package 4 is in package 3, and everything in package 3 is included in package 2, etc.

Comment: This was my original question, but it seemed to confuse people so I thought I would simplify it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385095/filter-in-ng-repeat-by-values

Comment: @ChristianHill wouldn't  a comparison table be more effective? Show all items on side and packages across top and use icons to show if included or not?

Comment: Hahaha, the UX isn't in my realm to decide, unfortunately. I'm just a lowly order taker. Stakeholders and UX analysts have already decided what the design is, I just have to code it. :(

Comment: @ChristianHill I changed the code example to use $scope. I also added some more objects in the array to show that if packagetype 2 is selected the 2 and 3 packages are shown. If that answered your question, please accept it. For future questions, please  look at the [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.